# Use selection in ex command

Tags: vim

How do I use a visual selection in an ex command in vim? For example, suppose I have selected the text `foo`, and I want to use this to run `:! open http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vmap` to yank the text and use it from the register 0:

```
 vmap <F2> y:!open http://hackage.haskell.org/package/<C-R>0<CR>
```

Comment: or you may want to add a `<Leader>` key based mapping